# Display values on seaborn swarmplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization, categorical-data

| ID | gender | age | job |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | male | 20 | Accountant |
| 02 | female | 21 | manager |
| 03 | male | 22 | IT engineer |
| 04 | female | 20 | manager |
| 05 | female | 20 | manager |
| 06 | male | 22 | IT engineer |

I have a data that looks like this. And I want to build a graph which shows information about each employee. Yaxis is the age of employee (continuous), xaxis is their job (categorical), the color represents gender, and the number inside each data point is the ID of that employee.
The result should look something like below:
[seaborn swarmplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fe7Z.png)

Would it be possible to create a graph like this? I'm open to new libraries, new methods.

Thank you

Comment: Seaborn's swarmplot doesn't support this kind of numbered labeling.

Comment: @JohanC Could you suggest another library/solution for this graph?